# Macintosh HD icon on desktop - make it open finder in desktop with toolbar?

Tags: finder

When I double click not the Macintosh HD icon on my desktop, it opens a window like so:

[image]

I would like it to open a window like so:

[image]

This is on a 2019 mbp running Mojave 10.14.6.

It is a recent update from a ~2016 mbap, where I have had that icon functioning in that desired way for many years. Also, that icon has functioned that way on my iMac at home for the past 7 years, and that's how it functions on my new home iMac (one week old).

I've no idea why I can't get that icon on my new (work) mbp to function that way. Could it be to do with not having admin rights? I had admin rights on the 3 other machines I refer to (previous work mbp, two home imacs) whereas I don't on my new work mbp.

Answer (score 1):

I think I know what the issue is here. You need to change the view settings for Finder when you're in the `Macintosh HD` directory that you clicked on from your desktop. I think any view settings you've set for a particular directory (i.e. `Macintosh HD`) is applied to the child directories you've clicked on from the same window.

The reason a new Finder window doesn't have the issue is because by default it opens the `~/AccountName` directory which had the view settings enabled for toolbar/path bar/status bar. So change the view settings when you're in `Macintosh HD` directory and it shouldn't have this problem in future. I've highlighted the view settings you need to enable in the screenshot below. [image] Let me know if this works for you.